# How can I re-start a GNU radio flowgraph after it has been stopped using a Head block?

Tags: gnuradio

I am running a gnu radio flowgraph in which I wish to save a fixed number of samples in a file every 30 seconds while performing signal processing on the samples stored in the file. To do this I am attempting to use a Head block. The Head block works fine to save the first group of samples but it stops the flowgraph. I need to re-start the flowgraph to save the next group of samples.

I was hoping to use the reset() method in the Head block but it doesn't do what I want to do. According to the gnu radio list "reset() should work *before* the Head block reaches the specified items, but once it reaches that number of items, Head is done and the flowgraph will terminate. So, I don't think reset() will do what you're hoping."

Is there any way to do what I am hoping? My code is as follows:

```
blocks_head_0 = blocks.head(gr.sizeof_float*1, 12000*15)

def rx(stop_rx):
        while not stop_rx.isSet():
            print("\nStarting RX")
            check_time(rx_cycle)
            parse_rx()
            time.sleep(8)
            blocks_head_0.reset()
            print("\nExiting RX")
```